# TypeError: close() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

So I tried using the function
`InteractiveSession.close()`
If I do it says:

> TypeError: close() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

But when I do
`InteractiveSession.close(self)`
It gives me the Error

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

I don't know what to do can anyone help? Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to call `.close()` on an *instance of* the `InteractiveSession` class, not the class itself.

For example, if you have an instance of `InteractiveSession` in the variable `session`, you would write `session.close()`.

Also note that TF developers helpfully provided a usage example here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/InteractiveSession

This question reflects a basic but common misunderstanding about how classes work in Python. There are many documents and guides that can help you on this topic, for example here is one I just found with a DDG search: https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0